# Escaping ampersand character with svn on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, dos

I am trying to run the following command:

```
svn.exe status "file://mycompany.net/IB-C&R-FO/TECHNOLOGY SECURE/"
```

I get the following error:

```
svn: warning: 'file://mycompany.net/IB-C' is not a working copy
'R-FO' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I escape the ampersand character in my file path? I've tried "&", "^&" and "\&"?

Comment: Try `file://mycompany.net/IB-C%26R-FO/TECHNOLOGY%20SECURE/`

Comment: `^&` is the proper way to escape the `&` symbol on the command line.